# how to get redux-persist working in nextjs 13.4 app directory using redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I'm about to setup a new project using nextjs using the new app router, I could set redux toolkit up using a provider based on official example in nextjs repository : https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux
but the problem is when I add redux-persist:

```
"use client";

import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
/* Core */
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

/* Instruments */
import { persistor, reduxStore } from "@/lib/redux";

export const Providers = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={reduxStore}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

also tried importing PersistGate using dynamic import:

```
"use client";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const PersistGateComponent = dynamic(
  () =>
    import("redux-persist/integration/react").then((mod) => mod.PersistGate),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

const SSROutset = ({ children, persistor }) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return (
      <PersistGateComponent persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </PersistGateComponent>
    );
  }

  // You can create a visually hidden component to avoid layout flashes and also maintain SEO content
  // see Chakra for an example of one https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/visually-hidden
  return (
    <span
      style={{
        border: "0",
        clip: "rect(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        height: "1px",
        width: "1px",
        margin: "-1px",
        padding: "0",
        overflow: "hidden",
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
        position: "absolute",
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </span>
  );
};

export default SSROutset
```

and:

```
"use client";

/* Core */
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

/* Instruments */
import { persistor, reduxStore } from "@/lib/redux";
import SSROutset from "./redux/SSROutset";

export const Providers = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={reduxStore}>
      <SSROutset persistor={persistor}>
        {children}
      </SSROutset>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

still getting following errors:

`Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`

Comment: I did it the same thing but I but children out of the persistGate 
Because when I have children in persist gate all page render client side not  server side

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with `useEffect`

```
const { list } = useAppSelector(state => state.example);

const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsMounted(true);
}, []);

return (
  <div>
     {isMounted && list.length > 0 && ( ... )}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: I don't see how is this relevant ?

Comment: I thought you were using data from the store in your components. And as I see you are getting a hydration error because the rendering on the client is different from rendering on the server. I got this error too and I decided to fix it by isMount flag in the state of component. I may be wrong on this matter, but it works

Comment: For this example I want to suggest using isMounted state in SSROutset:

`if (typeof window !== "undefined" && isMounted) {`

Answer (score 0):

I have work around this problem
the store initial

```js
import {
  addToCartMiddleware,
  updateCartMiddleware,
  deleteCartMiddleware,
} from "./slices/checkout/middleware";
import CheckoutLineReducer from "./slices/checkout/Line.Slice";

let store;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  notification: NotificationReducer,

});

const middlewares = [
  addToCartMiddleware,
  updateCartMiddleware,
  deleteCartMiddleware,
  thunk,
];

const persistConfig = {
  key: "primary",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["auth", "checkout"],
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

function makeStore() {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    middleware: middlewares,
  });
}

export const initializeStore = (preloadedState) => {
  let _store = store ?? makeStore();

  // For SSG and SSR always create a new store
  if (typeof window === "undefined") return _store;

  // Create the store once in the client
  if (!store) store = _store;

  return _store;
};

export function useStore() {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeStore(), []);
  return store;
}

export default makeStore;
```

and after that I make Provider component to wrap the project in Layout

```html
"use client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { useStore } from "@/lib/redux/store";

const ProviderWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const store = useStore();
  let persistor;

  if (store) {
    persistor = persistStore(store, {}, function () {
      persistor.persist();
    });
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<p>loading</p>} persistor={persistor} />
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default ProviderWrapper;
```

the persist store working but it makes alot of action in the
persist/PERSIST
persist/REYHIDRATION

note: in Provider I put children out of PersistCate because when you add it inside the persist gate all the application will be client side

Answer (score 0):

1. create a custom storage

```js
"use client";

import createWebStorage from "redux-persist/lib/storage/createWebStorage";

const createNoopStorage = () => {
  return {
    getItem(_key: any) {
      return Promise.resolve(null);
    },
    setItem(_key: any, value: any) {
      return Promise.resolve(value);
    },
    removeItem(_key: any) {
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
  };
};

const storage =
  typeof window !== "undefined"
    ? createWebStorage("local")
    : createNoopStorage();

export default storage;
```

2. use this custom storage on your persistConfig:

```js
import storage from "./customStorage";

// Redux persist config
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
};
```

3. Remove persistgate from your storeProvider, no need to delay the app since we're not using react directly but next, thus next config.

> If you are using react, wrap your root component with PersistGate. This delays the rendering of your app's UI until your persisted state has been retrieved and saved to redux (https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist?tab=readme-ov-file):

```js
"use client";
import { AppStore, makeStore } from "@/lib/store";
import { setupListeners } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";
import type { ReactNode } from "react";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";

interface Props {
  readonly children: ReactNode;
}

export const StoreProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore | null>(null);
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    // Create the store instance the first time this renders
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
    persistStore(storeRef.current);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (storeRef.current != null) {
      // configure listeners using the provided defaults
      // optional, but required for `refetchOnFocus`/`refetchOnReconnect` behaviors
      const unsubscribe = setupListeners(storeRef.current.dispatch);
      return unsubscribe;
    }
  }, []);
  return <Provider store={storeRef.current}>{children}</Provider>;
};
```