# Next.js 14: Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted for my react 18 web application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I have created a react app using `npx create-next-app@latest` command which is using react version 18 and next.js version 14.

Iam using `App router` for my project as recommended by `next.js` `14` version.

I have integrated `redux-toolkit` and `redux-persist` for my project for state management.

When i run app on browser., I see following error

`Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted` error
[image]

I have used `src/app` folder structure as recommended by `next.js 14` official documentation.

Routing was working fine before `redux-persist` was configured. it started breaking post that. when i commented hooks `useAppSelector` and `useAppDispatch` in my components., again routing started working.

This is my code configuration.

All redux data available in `src/lib` folder

```
// src/lib/store.ts

import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import RootReducer from "./RootReducer";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, RootReducer);

const makeConfiguredStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: RootReducer,
  });
export const makeStore = () => {
  const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";
  if (isServer) {
    return makeConfiguredStore();
  } else {
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, RootReducer);
    let store: any = configureStore({
      reducer: persistedReducer,
    });
    store.__persistor = persistStore(store);
    return store;
  }
};

export type AppStore = ReturnType<typeof makeStore>;
export type RootState = ReturnType<AppStore["getState"]>;
export type AppDispatch = AppStore["dispatch"];

export const persistor = persistStore(makeStore());
```

```
// src/lib/RootReducer.ts
import { combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import SliceReducer from "@/slices/mySlice";

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
  MySlice: SliceReducer,
});

export default RootReducer;
```

```
// src/lib/hooks.ts
import { useDispatch, useSelector, useStore } from "react-redux";
import type { TypedUseSelectorHook } from "react-redux";
import type { RootState, AppDispatch, AppStore } from "./store";

export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch;
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
export const useAppStore: () => AppStore = useStore;
```

All pages available in `src/app` folder

```
// src/app/layout.tsx
"use client";
import { useRef } from "react";
import "./globals.css";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { Box, Grid } from "@mui/material";
import { AppStore, makeStore, persistor } from "@/lib/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import Leftsidebar from "./components/Leftsidebar";

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const storeRef = useRef<AppStore>();
  if (!storeRef.current) {
    storeRef.current = makeStore();
  }
  return (
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current.__persistor}>
        <html lang="en">
          <body>
            <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
              {pathName !== "/" && <Header />}
              {children}
            </Box>
          </body>
        </html>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

```
// src/app/page.tsx
import React from "react";
import LoginComp from "@/components/login";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <LoginComp />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

All components available in `src/components` folder

```
// src/components/login.tsx
"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Container,
  TextField,
  Button,
  Box,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { setDashboardData } from "@/redux/slices/DashboardSlice";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppStore, useAppSelector } from "@/lib/hooks";

const LoginComp: React.FC = () => {
  const store = useAppStore();
  const router = useRouter();
  const handleLoginClick = () => {
    const stateData = { message: "Dashboard page" };
    store.dispatch(setDashboardData(stateData));
    router.push("/dashboard");
  };
  return (
    <Box>
      <Container maxWidth="xs">
        <Box margin="normal">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleLoginClick}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Box>
      </Container>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default LoginComp;
```

Since `AppRouter` is new., iam bit confused with approach. please help me if any above created flow is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76840499/how-to-get-redux-persist-working-in-nextjs-13-4-app-directory-using-redux-toolki"

Comment: @Mushood: Not exactly. Though I could see some of issues in that discussions was relevant., but not the solution.

Comment: I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77783551/how-to-use-redux-persist-with-next-js-app-router as well.. no luck..

Answer (score 2):

finally found the answer for my issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74515807/uncaught-error-invariant-expected-app-router-to-be-mounted)

Though I have `<html>` tag inside `layout.tsx` ., I tried to wrap `html` tag inside `<Provider>` ., But `<Provider> should be inside <html> and <body> tag` since `Next.js` by default wont create `html` tag.

so., I here is the modified code snippets:

**Before:**

```js
<Provider store={storeRef.current}>
  <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current}>
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        ...
      </body>
    </html>
  </PersistGate>
</Provider>
```

**After:**

```js
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <Provider store={storeRef.current}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={storeRef.current}>
        ....
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which `solved` my issue